# Springboot returns JSON, IE browser tries to download the JSON as a file

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Using [Springboot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) to build a project. You can use the configuration to solve the problem when you don't use Springboot to build the project, but now I don't know how to configure it.

```
@RestController
public class RestShowNameController {
    @RequestMapping("/myself")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/object")
    public User object() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("绿秋");
        user.setComment("系统管理员用户");
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has some error? or do you want to learn to configure the Springboot?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not configured

Comment: when you return a `ModelAndView` from a method, you cannot use `@RestController`, you need `@Controller` then. And when changing that, you need to add `@ResponseBody` to your `object()`method

Answer (score 0):

This is IE's property to prompt for opening the JSON file.  If you will try this in other browsers (like chrome) it will directly display the results on screen.

If you want to change the method to display on screen for IE also. One way can be to change the method to return String, as 
you are returning an object as response and its getting converted to JSON by default:

```
@RestController
public class RestShowNameController {
    @RequestMapping("/myself")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/object")
    @ResponseBody
    public String object() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("绿秋");
        user.setComment("系统管理员用户");
        return user.toString();
    }
}
```

In User class override the toString() method and format the result.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [name =" + name + ", comment =" + comment + "]";
}
```